# Merge two Eloquent Collections and remove all duplicates.

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have two arrays, `$user_roles` and `$global_roles`. I want to make a new array, let's call it `$available_roles`, where it can be equated as the items in `$global_roles` less the items in the `$user_roles`

I have the following code to do it to a normal array. `$available_roles = array_unique(array_merge($global_roles, $user_roles), SORT_REGULAR);`

This is proving to be problematic due to the fact that Laravel does not use traditional arrays when one executes a query, it uses Eloquent Collections.

What other ideas do you guys have?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is fairly simple. You can use the Collection's `merge` method:

```
$available_roles = $global_roles->merge($user_roles);
```

Because `merge` internally uses an associative array (dictionary) that uses the id as key, this should automatically remove duplicates.

Anyways though, you can remove duplicates in a collection using `unique`:

```
$uniqueCollection = $collection->unique();
```

---

Now that was for *merging* what you're actually are looking for is the *difference* between two collections. You can do this in two ways:

```
$available_roles = $user_roles->diff($global_roles);
```

or

```
$available_roles = $global_roles->except($user_roles->modelKeys());
```

Comment: I understand how it is supposed to work, but it doesn't seem to be working the way that I intended it to. 

Here is a picture of what the Two Collections are looking like rendered. (http://i.imgur.com/JGIN5en.png) 

If my reasoning is correct, shouldn't the available roles be empty because the User already has the roles assigned to him

Comment: Ah I see. You are not trying to *merge* them at all. What you want is the difference between the two. Try `$available_roles = $user_roles->diff($global_roles);` or also `$available_roles = $global_roles->except($user_roles->modelKeys());`