# Laravel - Collection merge() returning a single row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a problem with Model Collections (Eloquent).

I have two Collection of the Model `ActivationDetail` and I need to merge them into a single collection, the collection have the same structure so it wouldn't be hard to merge them right?

Well, searched in the internet and the API itself I've came across the `merge()` method which allows me to combine two collections into one. Like found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30524136/7653705), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45580730/7653705), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29446416/7653705).

However, this method is returning me a single row. (`sizeof($detail)` is returning 1) Although in the correct format, I don't know what I'm missing here.

What I am doing wrong?

```
//first collection
$detail = ActivationDetail::[redacted]->get();

// second collection, the query is of the same structure 
// as the previous one, but it's edited to allow the selection 
// of null fields (which can't be possible in the previous 
// due how Inner Joins work)
$detailB = ActivationDetail::[redacted]->get();

$detail = $detail->merge($detailB);

//this returns "1"
dd(sizeof($detail));
```

Comment: Please show results of `dd($detail, $detailB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running two queries that have the same columns in the result set, you might want to take a look at [unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#unions). This will join the two queries in one query that merges the results for you.

```
$query1 = ActivationDetail::[redacted];
$detail = ActivationDetail::[redacted]->union($query1)->get();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!